# How to select where like multi line string in SQL text field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and have a table with a text column spanning many lines, like this:

```
[textfield]
blah blah
blah

yackety
shmackety

blah blah
```

I want to

```
select * 
from table
where [textfield] like '
%
yackety
shmackety
%
'
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your version?  It looks correct.

Comment: Honestly don't know, it just returns zero results. I dumped the field to notepad++ and set it to show all special characters and other than the CRLF there is nothing weird looking. But it definitely needs the char(13) + char(10) specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` wildcard also covers line breaks.

The problem with line breaks is that it's not always the same. Some use `char(10)`, some use `char(13)`, some use `char(13) + char(10)`, and of course, you can't *see* if there are white spaces before the line brake, so the easiest thing to do is to just use `%` whenever you are expecting a line brake:

```
select * 
from table
where [textfield] like '%yackety%shmackety%'
```

If you want to make sure there is at least one line break between the two words, you will have to do it a little different:

```
select * 
from table
where [textfield] like '%yackety%'+ char(10) +'%shmackety%'
or  [textfield] like '%yackety%'+ char(13) +'%shmackety%'
```

Comment: The first example returned nothing, but the second put me on the right track. The field uses char(13)+char(10) to linebreak so the solution was: `where [textfield] like '%yackety' + char(13)+char(10) + 'shmackety%'`

Comment: [I've got the result in both versions...](http://rextester.com/TRK83833)

Comment: @Gordon thanks for the spelling fix! there are some words I always get wrong, even in my native language :-)